# Intermediate between LinkedList and ArrayList

Tags: java, performance, data-structures, containers

In the following piece of code, I have the result of a query, but I have no clue about the total number of records. I have to store it into a container. When I read each record of the container, it will be a simple loop so that index-based access will not be used.

```
  List<MyObject> list;

  while ( source.hasNext() ) {
      MyObject ob = new MyObject();
      convertObject(ob, source.next());
      list.add(ob);
  }

  ...

  //Another method

  for (MyObject ob : objects){
    showThings(ob);
  }
```

**LinkedList** is poor because it creates many small objects with pointers to the next one. It uses more memory, makes the memory more fragmented and has more cache miss.

**ArrayList** is poor because I don't know the number of records that I will insert. Whenever I insert a new item and the inner array is full, it will allocate a bigger block of memory and copy everything to the new block.

I didn't find any solution in java.util. So I consider writing a custom list. It will be like a LinkedList, but each cell is an array. In other words, the first node will be like an ArrayList, but when it is full and I insert a new object, it will create another node with an array to insert the new items instead of copying everything. However, I may be reinventing the wheel somehow.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33737669/when-to-use-gluelist-over-arraylist-or-linkedlist

Comment: What specifically is your problem with ArrayList? Performance? Memory?

Comment: ArrayList has the overhead of moving the records when it runs out of space.

Comment: GlueList, which I didn't know that exist, is the solution. Thanks, that is the answer.

Comment: Solution for what? What's wrong with ArrayList?

Comment: why not instance `ArrayList<MyObject> list;` and then call method `.size()` ??

Comment: @MartinZeitler You mean `trimToSize()`?

Comment: @shmosel it reads "I have no clue about the total number of records" while `.size()` would return the count of (top-most) items; when being required to get count of nested items, one can still let those `<Object>` in the `ArrayList` make return their own size and add up that value in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I said "I have no clue about the total number of records", but I mean "I have no clue about the total number of records that I will insert". I can set the capacity of ArrayList, but it is not useful when the future number of records is unknown.

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I insert a new item and the inner array is full, it will allocate a bigger block of memory and copy everything to the new block

This is not true, you can preallocate a hash array of any size you want, and it only increments when it runs out of space, increasing by 50% each time, so if you have a reasonable guess of the expected size, or even guess a large number, the reallocation cost will be zero or minimal.

Comment: Is it correct to say _doubling each time_? I saw earlier implementations where the increase size isn't multiply by two...
Just asking for my better understanding. Ty.

Comment: @zlakad you are correct. Its usually 1.5x the size.

Comment: It used to be double but it changed since the last time I looked at the source.

Comment: @JimGarrison Thx. (BTW, I didn't down vote). Right now I'm looking at source code for `ArrayList`. And, there are somethings I don't like...

Answer (score 0):

Some googling unveils the [Brownies Collections' GapList](http://www.magicwerk.org/page-collections-overview.html).
It is organizing its contents in blocks and manages them by arranging them in a tree. It also does block merging in case after element removal they become sparse.

Comment: I have added information to show the relevance of this particular implementation. Further aspects I should improve in my answer?